# Remote Desktop with 3 different operating systems

Tags: linux, windows-7, remote-desktop, osx-lion

i work as a part-time problem solver in a small company. I can solve most of the problems from the command line remotely.

But when there is a problem on a client machine, i have to go to the company ... which is not the optimal solution.

I have a MacBook. The Server is Linux based and the only machine which is reachable remotely. The client machines have Windows 7 on it.

**Is it somehow possible to have something like a Remote Desktop tool (that is freely available)    and easy to setup/use?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess what... the [Remote Desktop Client is available for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client).  You can tunnel that through the linux server via ssh quite easily... or VPN in if you really need/want to.

Comment: Heck, you can even load the RDC on your iPhone!

Comment: This sounds promising! Could you point me to a resource, for tunneling the server via ssh ? :)

Comment: Sure: here's an old one... http://www.engadget.com/2006/03/21/how-to-ssh-tunnels-for-secure-network-access/  ... just remember the port for RDP is 3389... and to connect through the forwarded port... specify localhost:[port] instead of the remote's IP.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the alternative of VNC, VNC displays the remote desktop, or terminal in some cases. And VNC is available for just about every platform.

TightVNC is what I would recommend for a package: http://www.tightvnc.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can `ssh -c -X` to the Linux server and use `rdesktop` from there to the client machines.

Answer (score 0):

You can run teamviewer from the server or from your MAC, it might be required to adjust the firewall settings on the client's firewall.